# Is there a way to see the execution time and execution status in google colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run the notebook in google colab. I am wondering if there is way for me to know if the cell is run and how long it took to run the cell (in milliseconds)

Comment: [%%time](https://colab.research.google.com/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/01.07-Timing-and-Profiling.ipynb#scrollTo=FLUjSrPY5GYO) in Colab –

Answer (score 29):

You can do this to get the running time of each cell (similar to the ExecuteTime extension for Jupyter Notebook):

```
!pip install ipython-autotime
%load_ext autotime
```

This is how it'll look after running the above code:
[image]

Comment: Great! Add this at the beginning of CoLab script, then you see timestamp and timecost of every executed block!

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to get the combination of cells running time together?

Answer (score 11):

When you hover over the code block, you can see a sort of play button with a circular progression ring around while it's still running.

To track times, you can add `%%timeit` at the start of the execution block like

```
%%timeit
for i in range(1000):
    print(i)
# above is a placeholder for your code
```

and it will give you the time it took to run the code block in milliseconds.
Alternatively you can do `%timeit l = [i for i in range(10)] #placeholder for a single line of code` to get the execution time for the single line.

Comment: that is one way to check it by hovering over the play button. I am looking for a way if we can write a line of code in the notebook so that time execution will be printed after running each cell.

Comment: `%%timeit` serves that purpose.

Comment: @vinu `ipython-autotime` might help you looking up execution time of each cell without having to repeatedly type `%%timeit` [Relevant PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/ipython-autotime/)

Comment: Thanks so much. that's precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the execution time of absolutely anything by calculating the time taken

```
import time
t1 = time.perf_counter()

### Your code goes here ###

t2 = time.perf_counter()
print('time taken to run:',t2-t1)
```

Comment: Can we set something initially in the notebook so that the time executed will be shown in every cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can accumulate the time taken to run. Something simple but useful.

**Example:**

```python
import time

class Timer:

  def __init__(self):
    self.start = time.perf_counter()

  def calcMsUntil(self):
    return (time.perf_counter() - self.start) * 1000

# Cell [A]
print('\nCell [A] - start counter')
timer = Timer()

# Cell [B]
print('\nCell [B] - something happens (1 SECOND)')
time.sleep(1)

# Cell [C]
print('\nCell [C]')
print("time until [C]:", timer.calcMsUntil())

# Cell [D]
print('\nCell [D] - something happens (2 SECONDS)')
time.sleep(2)

# Cell [E]
print('\nCell [E]')
print("time until [E]:", timer.calcMsUntil())
```

**Result:**

```
Cell [A] - start counter

Cell [B] - something happens (1 SECOND)

Cell [C]
time until [C]: 1001.7266389995712

Cell [D] - something happens (2 SECONDS)

Cell [E]
time until [E]: 3005.6352470001
```